Link local gallery album to Supabase Storage Bucket
I would like to create a picture share app with React Native. The user should be able to synchronize a local gallery album with my supabase storage.
I can upload the images and download them locally. But how do I link the local album and the supabase storage folder?
Is there a better way then just have a local database and connect the local album id with the online album id?
